# Minecraft server shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, minecraft

I'm new here and I couldn't find this anywhere else. I wanted to write a quick bash script so I could stop having to copy/paste the following code into my linux server.

```
screen -S MineCraft -d -m java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I want to be able to punch in a simple command that will run the above command, IE: Minecraft or something of that sort.

Comment: By the way, this isn't a Linux support website, this is for questions specific to programming. I answered your question for you, but you'd be better off at **SuperUser** (google it).

Answer (score 2):

This is the shell script I've written for my Minecraft server.

save it as `start.sh` and call it with `./start.sh start`

You can also call backup, which creates a backup while the server can still run. This backup can be restored later.

Remember to change `craftbukkit.jar` into whatever your JAR file is.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Made by bytecode77
    ##############################################################
    DIRECTORY='/home/minecraft'
    SESSIONNAME='minecraftserverscreen'
    JARFILE='craftbukkit.jar'
    WORLDNAME='world'
    NETHERNAME='world_nether'
    SKYNAME='world_skylands'
    ENDNAME='world_the_end'
    ##############################################################

start()
{
    SCREENID=$(screen -ls | grep -w $SESSIONNAME | cut -f 2)
    if [ $SCREENID ]; then
        echo "Minecraft is already running."
    else
        echo "Starting Minecraft server..."
        screen -dmS $SESSIONNAME java -Xms768M -Xmx768M -jar $JARFILE nogui
    fi
}

stop()
{
    SCREENID=$(screen -ls | grep -w $SESSIONNAME | cut -f 2)
    if [ $SCREENID ]; then
        echo "Stopping Minecraft server..."
        screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`"
        while screen -ls | grep $SESSIONNAME > /dev/null
        do
            sleep 0.1
        done
    else
        echo "Minecraft is not running."
    fi
}

restart()
{
    echo "Restarting Minecraft server..."
    stop > /dev/null && start > /dev/null
}

saveoff()
{
    screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "say Starting backup..."\015'
    screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "save-off"\015'
    screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "save-all"\015'
    sync
}

saveon()
{
    screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "save-on"\015'
    screen -S $SESSIONNAME -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "say Backup complete."\015'
}

backup()
{
    echo "Creating backup of '$WORLDNAME', '$NETHERNAME', '$SKYNAME' and '$ENDNAME'..."
    saveoff
    sleep 5
    mkdir -p backups
    tar cfv "backups/NEW.tar" $WORLDNAME $NETHERNAME $SKYNAME $ENDNAME > /dev/null
    mv "backups/NEW.tar" "backups/$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S").tar"
    saveon
}

restore()
{
    echo "Restoring '$WORLDNAME', '$NETHERNAME', '$SKYNAME' and '$ENDNAME'..."
    stop > /dev/null
    rm -r $WORLDNAME
    rm -r $NETHERNAME
    rm -r $SKYNAME
    rm -r $ENDNAME
    tar xfv "backups/$(ls backups -t | head -1 | grep ".tar")" > /dev/null
    start > /dev/null
}

cd $DIRECTORY

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    backup)
        backup
    ;; 
    restore)
        restore
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: ${0} {start|stop|restart|backup|restore}"
        exit 2
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: How can I do this with Windows?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know as I'm only hosting a Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

First:

`$ nano runMinecraft`

Type this in:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S MineCraft -d -m java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
```

Save it, type this in:

`$ chmod +X runMinecraft`

Then, to run Minecraft, simply type:

`$ ./runMinecraft`

You can also copy `runMinecraft` to `/usr/bin/` so you don't have to type the `./` every time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_aliases` files, add an alias to `~/.bash_aliases` (`man alias` for more information)

Alternatively (Also reliant on `~/.profile`) add an executable bash script to `~/bin` with the correct shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and it should also run.

If missing the files, copy them from `/etc/skel`

```
cd /etc/skel
cp .profile .bash_aliases ~
echo 'alias minecraft="screen -S MineCraft -d -m java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"' | tee -a ~/.bash_aliases
```

relog and it should work